# Разработать программу вычисления по приведенной формуле (C#) (Исправить ошибки)

Tags: c#, консоль

Разработать программу вычисления по приведенной формуле F(x) и вывести на экран результат в указанном формате. Исходные данные вводятся с клавиатуры. Сравнить полученное значение с указанным правильным результатом. В чём трабо

```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение x: ");
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение a: ");
        double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double result = Math.Sin((Math.PI + x) / 20) + Math.Pow(x + 1, 1.0 / a) + Math.Sqrt(x) - 7.2 * x * a * Math.Log(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x), 2) * Math.Pow(x, -3));

        double comparisonResult = 1.0021 * Math.Pow(10, 3);

        Console.WriteLine($"Результат вычисления: {result}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Сравнение с правильным результатом: {result == comparisonResult}");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение с корнем неправильно сделано, под логарифмом тоже не пойми что

```
 double result = Math.Sin((Math.PI + x) / 20) + 
                 Math.Sqrt(x + Math.Pow(x + 1, 1.0 / a)) - 
                 7.2 * x * a * Math.Log(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(Math.Pow(x, -3)), 2));
```

Константа записывается так:

```
    double comparisonResult = 1.0021e3;
```

И сравнение вещественных чисел на точное равенство не всегда даёт ожидаемый результат, нужно сравнивать с учётом погрешности, но в данном случае, думаю, вам нужно просто вывести константу и полученный результат

```
   Console.WriteLine($"Результат вычисления: {result}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Правильный результат: {сomparisonResult}");
```

Если нужно выводить так, как показана константа - в экспоненциальном формате с четырьмя знаками после запятой, то

```
Console.WriteLine("Результат вычисления: {0:E4}", result);
Console.WriteLine("Правильный результат: {0:E4}", comparisonResult);
```

[Тест](https://onlinegdb.com/JFBddbW3P)

```
Результат вычисления: 1.0021E+003
Правильный результат: 1.0021E+003
```